# Convert Scala Code to Python for Reporting

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I have this code in Scala and not massively familiar with Python to be able to convert it:

```
val formatterComma = java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance

def createTD(value: String) : String = {
  return s"""<td align="center" style="border:1px solid">${value}</td>"""
}

def createTD(value: BigInt) : String = {
  return createTD(value.toString)
}

def createTDDouble(value: Double) : String = {
  return createTD("$" + formatterComma.format(value))
}

def createTheLink(productId: String) : String = {
  return s"""<td align="center" style="border:1px solid"><a href="https://productLink/$product>Link Here</a></td>"""
}

def createTH(value: String) : String = {
  return s"""<th class="gmail-highlight-red gmail-confluenceTh gmail-tablesorter-header gmail-sortableHeader gmail-tablesorter-headerUnSorted" tabindex="0" scope="col" style="width:1px;white-space:nowrap;border:1px solid #000000;padding:7px 15px 7px 10px;vertical-align:top;text-align:center;background:100% 50% no-repeat">
            <div class="gmail-tablesorter-header-inner" style="margin:0px;padding:0px"><h2 title="" style="margin:0.2px 0px 0px;padding:0px;font-size:20px;font-weight:normal;line-height:1.5;letter-spacing:-0.008em;border-bottom-color:rgb(50,199,208))"><strong>${value}</strong></h2>
            </div>
            </th>"""
}

final case class resultsOfReport (name: String, email: String, phone:String, productId : String, product: String,  cost : Double, reduction : Double);

def runReport(elements: Array[resultsOfReport]): String = {
  return elements.map {
        case resultsOfReport (name, email, phone, productId, product, cost, stillInStock)
         => s"""<tr>${createTD(name)}${createTD(email)}${createTD(phone)}${createTD(productId)}${createTD(product)}${createTDDouble(cost)}${createTDDouble(reduction)}${createTheLink(productId)}${createTD("Link to product")}</tr>"""
      }.mkString(s"""<table class="gmail-relative-table gmail-confluenceTable gmail-tablesorter gmail-tablesorter-default" style="border-collapse:collapse; margin:0px;overflow-x:auto;width:1200px"><tr>
               ${createTH("Name")}
                 ${createTH("Email")}
                 ${createTH("Phone")}
               ${createTH("ProductId")}
                ${createTH("Product")}
                 ${createTH("Cost")}
             ${createTH("Reduction")}
             ${createTH("Link")}
</tr>""","",
        "</table>")
}
```

It takes in data passed through the runReport method and maps it to the appropriate columns. Creating a table with the data which I send out.

I need to be able to use a python method inside this and cannot call a python method in Scala in databricks.

I've started to convert it but then got stuck on how to make it work like the scala method:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class runReport:
  name: str
  email: str
  phone: str
  productId: str
  product: str
  cost: float
  reduction: float
        
def runReport(runReport):
```

Edit: So from trying out things. I guess the only thing I need to be able to do is work out how to do this part in python:

```
 return elements.map {
        case resultsOfReport (name, email, phone, productId, product, cost, stillInStock)
         => s"""<tr>${createTD(name)}${createTD(email)}${createTD(phone)}${createTD(productId)}${createTD(product)}${createTDDouble(cost)}${createTDDouble(reduction)}${createTheLink(productId)}${createTD("Link to product")}</tr>"""
      }.mkString(s"""<table class="gmail-relative-table gmail-confluenceTable gmail-tablesorter gmail-tablesorter-default" style="border-collapse:collapse; margin:0px;overflow-x:auto;width:1200px"><tr>
               ${createTH("Name")}
                 ${createTH("Email")}
                 ${createTH("Phone")}
               ${createTH("ProductId")}
                ${createTH("Product")}
                 ${createTH("Cost")}
             ${createTH("Reduction")}
             ${createTH("Link")}
</tr>""","",
        "</table>")
```

The data comes in as [`Row(Name='name'` etc for example. Need to know how to map out these Row key values to column headers as it's in Scala above.

Edit:

Expected input:

```
data = spark.sql("select * from test")
```

data from sql example dataframe:

name=jon, email=email.com, phone=324234, productId=1234, product=new, cost=500, stillInStock=y)

Calling the resultsOfReport method as written above in Scala:

```
html_returned=resultsOfReport(data)
```

The expected output will give me the html format as I have given above in scala.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which functionality you need to call in **Python** that you do not have in **Scala**? - Also, as an advice, `return` is not needed and usually avoided: https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I have another notebook in python that encodes metrics etc which eventually forms a URL. I will be using that in this report. The library for encoding wasn't available in Scala. In the notebook I have it's a python notebook but I can run Scala commands too.  Thanks for the return advice I will take it out.

Comment: `spark.sql` should return a Dataframe, not a single Row object...

Comment: Pyspark supports SQL UDFs, which appears to be what you want

Comment: @OneCricketeer yep my bad, I'm not at home to check how the data is exactly returned. In scala as you can see in the code above I pass it in as array elements but this is just setting an Array variable from sql.Context. I want to do similar as possible in python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose it is quite simple to convert the first functions to their Python equivalents : `create_td`, `create_td_double`, `create_the_link` and `create_th`.

The function `runReport` can be written as bellow. You could use the type `List[Row]` as you can not convert DataFrame into dataclass as in Scala to case class:

```
from typing import List
from pyspark.sql.types import Row

def run_report(elements: List[Row]) -> str:
    table_header = f"""<table class="gmail-relative-table gmail-confluenceTable gmail-tablesorter gmail-tablesorter-default" style="border-collapse:collapse; margin:0px;overflow-x:auto;width:1200px"><tr>
                   {create_th("Name")}
                   {create_th("Email")}
                   {create_th("Phone")}
                   {create_th("ProductId")}
                   {create_th("Product")}
                   {create_th("Cost")}
                   {create_th("Reduction")}
                   {create_th("Link")}</tr>"""

    tables_tds = [
        f"""<tr>{create_td(el.name)}{create_td(el.email)}{create_td(el.phone)}{create_td(el.productId)}{create_td(el.product)}{create_td_double(el.cost)}{create_td_double(el.reduction)}{create_the_link(el.productId)}{create_td("Link to product")}</tr>"""
        for el in elements
    ]

    return table_header + "".join(tables_tds) + "</table>"
```

Using it:

```
data = spark.sql("select * from test").collect()
html_returned = run_report(data)
```

Note that `collect` should not be used for large DataFrames (I assume it's not very large for this use case).

Comment: Why not map `run_report` over the `spark.sql` result like was originally done?

Comment: There is `mapInPandas`. But otherwise, toRDD would be better than using collect, that's my main point

Comment: @OneCricketeer Of course, that's why I added a note for the use of collect in my answer. And actually, all these transformations can be done using simple Spark SQL built-in functions on DataFrame, no need to use RDDs. But as per my understanding, the OP wants to keep the same logic as in Scala.

Comment: @blackbishop thank you for your help with this and I will be using this. I think last week I just coded so much didn't think. I've used a different way where I can put the data into a dataframe and merge it with the existing data I have. But I will 100% use this code you have above in the future and will select this and the answer.